# Mapear usando Jackson com herança

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

Eu tenho a classe QueueContent que tem é uma superclasse de outras duas.

Recebo uma String em formato JSON que contem as informações que preciso extrair. A super classe é:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class QueueContent {

    private String empresa;
    private String empresa_cor;
    private String empresa_contato;
    private String empresa_url;
    private String empresa_telefone;
    private String empresa_idioma;

    public QueueContent(String empresa, String empresa_cor, String empresa_contato, String empresa_url, String empresa_telefone, String empresa_idioma) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.empresa_cor = empresa_cor;
        this.empresa_contato = empresa_contato;
        this.empresa_url = empresa_url;
        this.empresa_telefone = empresa_telefone;
        this.empresa_idioma = empresa_idioma;
    }

    public QueueContent() {
    }
}
```

(Estou usando Lombok para gerar Getters/Setters)

Essa é a classe filha:

```
@Data
public class EmailCameraOffline extends  QueueContent {
    private Timestamp camera_last_online;
    private String camera_nome;
    private String empresa_url_plataforma;

    public EmailCameraOffline(String empresa, String empresa_cor, String empresa_contato, String empresa_url, String empresa_telefone, String empresa_idioma, Timestamp camera_last_online, String camera_nome, String empresa_url_plataforma) {
        super(empresa, empresa_cor, empresa_contato, empresa_url, empresa_telefone, empresa_idioma);
        this.camera_last_online = camera_last_online;
        this.camera_nome = camera_nome;
        this.empresa_url_plataforma = empresa_url_plataforma;
    }

    public EmailCameraOffline() {
    }
}
```

Meu mapeamento é feito da seguinte forma:

```
               EmailCameraOffline infosEmail = new ObjectMapper().readValue(content, EmailCameraOffline.class);
                System.out.println(infosEmail);
```

E o output é:

> EmailCameraOffline(camera_last_online=2020-03-12 03:01:45.0,
>   camera_nome=Pier Cam 1, empresa_url_plataforma=null)

Como faço para meu objeto EmailCameraOffline ter os atributos da superclasse inicializados?

Comment: o object mapper tem uma propriedade chamada enabledefaulttyping(), em tese ela permite esse preenchimento através da herança, testa ai por favor

Comment: Não serviu :( E está marcado como deprecated;

Comment: que versão do jackson você esta usando? copiei suas classes aqui e testei contra a versão 2.2.3 e deu certo

Comment: Estou usando a 2.10.3!

Comment: edita a pergunta com o json que você está enviando por gentileza